# Characteristic function of normal vector

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, characteristic-functions

I'm going through an old exam in probability theory. The question reads:

> Let $X_1,\,X_2,\,X_3$ be $N(1,\,1)$ IIDs. Determine the characteristic function of the vector $U = X_1 + X_2 + X_3,\, V = X_2 + X_3,\,W = X_3$.

I tried using the transformation theorem to get the density of the vector $(U,V,W)$ and proceeding from there, but couldn't get it to work. I'm sure there's a really short solution to this problem since it's, judging by the number of points it gives, considered an easy exercise.

Comment: Which three letters (I've used $r,\,s,\,t$) would you like for the arguments? For example:$$\varphi(r,\,s,\,t)=\Bbb E[\exp i(rU+sV+tW)]$$

Comment: Hint: let $\varphi(t):=E[\exp(itX_1)]$ denote the characteristic function of $N(1,\,1)$ (evaluation is an exercise). The vector's charateristic function is$$\Bbb E[\exp i((r+s+t)X_1+(s+t)X_2+tX_3)]=\varphi(r+s+t)\varphi(s+t)\varphi(t)$$by the independence of the $X_j$.

Comment: Thanks! I get it now. I think you got the variables mixed up though and it should be r that appears 3 times in the final formula and t only ones (since X3 appears in all 3 r.v.'s and X1 only in U).

Comment: Whoops! Looks like you're right.